# Determine position changes between two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays

```
$array1 = ["name1","name2","name3","name4"];
$array2 = ["name2","name1","name3","name4"];
```

What I would like to know is the position changes between the arrays. In the above example the output will be:

```
$returnArray = [
    "name2"=>"up",
    "name1"=>"down",
    "name3"=>"same",
    "name4"=>"same"
];
```

*up* = moved position up

*down* = moved position down

*same* = stayed on the same position

What is the quickest way to determine the position changes comparing the two arrays?

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Yes I tried by using array_search and compare the returning values, but i think that is a complicated solution. I think it could be quicker.

Comment: quickest way to write some code and stop expecting ready made solutions from language OR SO

Comment: @Mrlitty Then ^^ show your attempt in your question

Comment: I do not expect any line of code. I expect a train of thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just loop through all unique values of `$array1` and check with `array_search()`
 if the value is at the same position, down or up.

```
<?php

    $array1 = ["name1","name2","name3","name4"];
    $array2 = ["name2","name1","name3","name4"];
    $result = [];

    foreach(array_unique($array1) as $k => $v){
        $result[$v] = $k == array_search($v, $array2) ? "same" : ($k < array_search($v, $array2) ? "up": "down");
    }

    print_r($result);

?>
```

And in PHP 7 just use the spaceship operator, e.g.

```
<?php

    $array1 = ["name1","name2","name3","name4"];
    $array2 = ["name2","name1","name3","name4"];
    $arr = ["-1" => "down", "0" => "same", "1" => "up"];
    $result = [];

    foreach(array_unique($array1) as $k => $v){
        $result[$v] = $arr[array_search($v, $array2) <=> $k];
    }

    print_r($result);

?>
```

Comment: I was hoping for a quicker method, but I think this is the quickest one.